# database structure for facebook wall type requirement

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, database-design

I am working on a social networking site and it has a wall like facebook where user can post status, pics and stuff. Building a wall just for a user is not hard thing. I have structure like this.

```
Wall
  {
     Id,
     ToUserId (BigInt) (Owner of wall)
     ByUserId (The person who is posting)
     Content  (message, pic or something else)
     more fields....
  }
```

This wall is just for a user, I cant reuse it, For example, I am thinking site will have 
other objects too like Pages, Groups etc. so all the objects will have Wall for them. I dont want to create separate table for each wall.

Then I thought, I can have ObjectId instead of ToUserId and my structure will be like this.

```
  Wall
  {
     Id,
     ObjectId (BigInt)(PageId/UserId/GroupId (one of them))
     ByUserId (The person who is posting)
     Content  (message, pic or something else)
     more fields....
  }
```

As I am using Increment field in my tables, A page can have same Id which a user has. so that is again a problem.

Next, I thought, my object should be string type

```
Wall
  {
     Id,
     ObjectId (string(10))(PageId/UserId/GroupId (one of them))
     ByUserId (The person who is posting)
     Content  (message, pic or something else)
     more fields....
  }
```

Now for a User, I will append "U" to the number so Object Id's will be "1U","2U" and for pages they will be "1P","2P" and for a group "1G", "2G".

But I am still not convince, Would like to hear to expert advice on this.

Update

Thanks guys, The problem, I am having is, how can I keep one table for all types of walls.

```
A wall for a User
A Wall for a Page
A Wall for a Group
```

If you look at facebook, its one wall or atleast, I want to build it, so it should be attached to any object (to a user, to a page or to a group or to anything).

I hope this makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you're trying to create some kind of "string" reference structure. That doesn't seem "relational".

How about this.

> A **User** has *many* **Posts**.
>
> A **User** has *one* **Wall**.
>
> A **Post** has *one* **Wall**.
>
> A **Post** has *one* **User**.
>
> A **Wall** has *many* **Posts**.
>
> A **Wall** has *one* **User**.

POCO's (because i can't be bothered writing SQL)

```
public class User
{
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; } // the Posts this user has written. Could be against different Wall's
   public Wall Wall { get; set; } // the User's wall.
}

public class Post
{
   public int PostId { get; set; }
   public User User { get; set; } // the User who wrote the post. 
   public Wall Wall { get; set; } // the Wall this Post belongs to. 
}

public class Wall
{
   public int WallId { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; } // all the posts on this Wall.
}
```

Assumptions:

- A **Post** can only be done against one **Wall**.

Comment: Thanks RPM, I am trying to avoid strings thats why I am asking this question here.

Comment: Say, I have one more object Page. Now the Page also has a wall. How to do that. ??

Comment: I think you need a kind of "UserType" flag (TINYINT) discriminating the type of User. 1 = User, 2 = Group, 3 = Page, etc.

Comment: Thanks RPM, I was trying to avoid composite key, but i feel I cant. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for separate nullable fields for each possible reference. This will also allow you to use foreign keys and if you want you can even make check contraint so all rows must have exactly one reference defined. I'd definitely NOT recommend going for that string id idea - it would be ineffective to do joins on that.

```
create table [Posts]
(
    [ID] int not null identity(1, 1),
    [ID_FromUser] int not null,
    [ID_ToUser] int null,
    [ID_ToPage] int null,
    [ID_ToGroup] int null,
    [Content] nvarchar(max) not null,
    -- more stuff

    constraint [FK_Posts_FromUser] foreign key ([ID_FromUser]) references [Users]([ID]),
    constraint [FK_Posts_ToUser] foreign key ([ID_ToUser]) references [Users]([ID]),
    constraint [FK_Posts_ToPage] foreign key ([ID_ToPage]) references [Pages]([ID]),
    constraint [FK_Posts_ToGroup] foreign key ([ID_ToGroup]) references [Groups]([ID]),
    constraint [PK_Posts] primary key ([ID])
)
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas, but with this approach, everytime two column will be blank. Moreover what if you want to add one more object, you would need to change db structure.